# Windows batch append value from properties to PATH

Tags: batch-file, cmd

test.properties

```
PATH=C\:\\dev\\jdk;%PATH%
```

tool.cmd

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (test.properties) DO (set %%A=%%B)
```

PATH before: `C:\dev\soft\what;C:\dev\soft\something`

PATH after expected: `C:\dev\jdk;C:\dev\soft\what;C:\dev\soft\something`

PATH after actual: `C\:\\dev\\jdk;%PATH%`

Basically, I want to add something to `PATH` with batch script, and that 'something' comes from properties file, which is the problem.

Hardcoded `set PATH=C\:\\dev\\jdk;%PATH%` works, but when the value comes from properties - it doesn't. For-loop variable is treated as text, and hardcoded one is resolved, I have no idea why. How to solve this?

Comment: Is there an error in your submitted `test.properties` file content? Should ```C\:\\dev\\jdk``` not read as ```C:\\dev\\jdk``` to translate to ```C:\dev\jdk```?

Comment: It was saved like this by java `Properties` class, and the String was `Path.toAbsolutePath().toString()` so I assume it is correct. But I'm reading this with batch file that doesn't know about `.properties` escaping, so I need to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently I fixed it with:

```
call set %%A=%%B
```

Can someone who actually knows this stuff confirm that this is not just an accident?

Comment: Yes, the `call` is needed so that `%PATH%` actually expands to its full value.